# recommended image resource to display sprite

Tags: iphone, image, cocos2d-iphone

I have some images which I would like to use as sprites in my game.

What is the best way to do this. I know .png , but Should the background be white, black, does the image, e.g. the character image , need to be "cut" out along its edges?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background can be whatever color you like.  It all depends on your needs. Doesn't need to be cut out.  Ultimately you need to save your image as a rectangle of some dimensions or another.  From your description sounds like you'll want to make some pixels transparent for your images.  Most paint programs will do that for you.